# Woocommerce Product Default Description for All Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

Is this possible to add Woocommerce Product Default Description for All Products page. That should be image or Note text. And I want It will be put in above or bottom of the description text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use hooks like

```
// define the woocommerce_single_product_summary callback function
function my_custom_action() { 
    echo '<p>This is my custom action function</p>';
};     
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );
```

or
woocommerce_after_single_product_summary

```
// define the woocommerce_after_single_product_summary callback 
function action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary( $evolve_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary, $int ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 10, 2 );
```

or woocommerce_before_single_product_summary

```
// define the woocommerce_before_single_product_summary callback 
function action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary( $woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash, $int ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 10, 2 );
```

or you may also change direct on woo-commerce files.

Comment: you may use other hooks try to add <p> tag into other hooks.