# Move product description after short description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I've used the first option of this hook (the other ones didn't work) -> [Woocommerce Product Default Description for All Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449109/woocommerce-product-default-description-for-all-products/51368829#51368829)

[And this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrt4M.png) (the red marked text is the standard description)

However, I want the text to appear after the product description. [where the red arrow is, I want the standard text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUq0y.png) So above 'in winkelmand' (which means 'add to bag')

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what to delete and what to replace.... this is how it now looks: // define the woocommerce_single_product_summary callback function
function my_custom_action() { 
    echo '<p>Heb je een vraag over dit product? Neem gerust contact op met de<a href="https://poesch.nl/neem-contact-op-met-poesch/" target="_blank"> klantenservice, </a> stuur een <a href="https://www.facebook.com/POESCHnl/" target="_blank">privé berichtje via Facebook </a> of klik op de chat rechts onder.</p>';
};     
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with the following code *(commented)*:

```
// 1. Remove the description product tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_descrip_product_tab', 98 );
function remove_descrip_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    // Remove the description tab
    unset( $tabs['description'] );

    return $tabs;
}

// 2. Add the product description after the product short description
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 25 );
function my_custom_action() {
    global $post;

    // Product description output
    echo '<div class="product-post-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>'; 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I don't understand what to delete and what to replace.... this is how it now looks: // define the woocommerce_single_product_summary callback function
function my_custom_action() { 
    echo '<p>Heb je een vraag over dit product? Neem gerust contact op met de<a href="https://poesch.nl/neem-contact-op-met-poesch/" target="_blank"> klantenservice, </a> stuur een <a href="https://www.facebook.com/POESCHnl/" target="_blank">privé berichtje via Facebook </a> of klik op de chat rechts onder.</p>';
};     
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );

Comment: When I add it, I get this message:

The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 17:

Cannot redeclare my_custom_action() (previously declared in /home/poesch.nl/public_html/nieuwewebsite.poesch.nl/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(352) : eval()'d code:3)

Comment: which one do I use now?  // 1. Remove the description product tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_descrip_product_tab', 98 );
function remove_descrip_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    // Remove the description tab
    unset( $tabs['description'] );

    return $tabs;
}

// 2. Add the product description after the product short description
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 25 );
function my_custom_action() {
    global $post;

    // Product description output
    echo '<div class="product-post-content">' . the_content() . '</div>';
}

Comment: if that's the one to use, it still causes a fatal error

Comment: @Lianne Sorry this code just work fine… I have test it again. So you are doing something wrong, when adding it to your function.php file.

Comment: so I should use the code above AND this one???


 // define the woocommerce_single_product_summary callback function
function my_custom_action() { 
    echo '<p>This is my custom action function</p>';
};     
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );

Comment: fix line: echo '<div class="product-post-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';

Answer (score 5):

That one did not work for me either, so I kept looking and found this one, which worked perfectly

`// Move Description to Under Price WooCommerce`

```
    function woocommerce_template_product_description() {wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );}

    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 20 );
```